# hide and show input text based on drop down selection however

Tags: javascript, jquery

hide and show input text based on drop down selection however the "input text" doesn't show anymore when i submit the form and I didn't complete the form validaton.

i am using jquery, and i can show and hide, works perfectly, but this part is bugging me alot.

my customers will not complete all the form fields, so when they submit the form, i would like them to SEE the input text based on their drop down selection, RATHER, the input text is missing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#shipping').change(function() {
        if ( $("#shipping").val ()  ==  "LA") 
        {                              
            $('#mydiv').show();
        }
        else
            $("#mydiv").hide();
    }); 
});

<select name="shipping" id="shipping">
 <option value="LA">LA</option>
 <option value="NYC">NYC</option>
</select>

<tr id="mydiv" style="display:none">
<td><input type="text" name="testing"></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="testing2"></td>
</tr>



<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="testing3"></td>
</tr>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: Please post your html also.

Comment: Its better to share a fiddle on this!

Comment: Your mydiv has style as "display:none" by default.. Remove that & you can see it.

Comment: but i only want it show when i select from the drop down? i did removed it and now its NOT doing what i want. basically, i only want to show that input text when i select from drop down, and have it STAY on the screen.

Comment: If this is your actual HTML, you ought to close your `input` tags. (This will NOT solve your problem, but it's another correction)

Comment: Do you want the value from the drop-down to show up in one of the inputs, or just show `tr` named 'mydiv'(which contains nothing)?  I'm not clear on what exactly you want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chaitu18mhyd/SysSA/) here. It works.
I don't see the `<table>` tag in your html, which is a problem.

```
<select name="shipping" id="shipping">
    <option value="select">Select</option>
    <option value="LA">LA</option>
    <option value="NYC">NYC</option>
</select>
<table>
<tr id="mydiv" style="display:none">
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="testing" value="show/hide"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="testing2"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="testing3"/>
    </td>
</tr>
    </table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Javascript:

```
$('#shipping').change(function () {
    if ($("#shipping").val() == "LA") {
        $('#mydiv').show();
    } else $("#mydiv").hide();
});
```

Comment: did you add the <table> wrapper tag as I clarified on top?

Answer (score 0):

what you want to validate.

```
if textbox is hidden , it should be part of validation or not 
if that is part of validation use 
$('#id').prop("required", "true");
else
$('#id').removeAttr("required");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inline styles for this try using a class for hiding it initially like,

```
<tr id="mydiv" class="hidden">
<td><input type="text" name="testing"></td>
</tr>
```

CSS: `.hidden{display:none;}`

and then do,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#shipping').change(function() {
        if ( $("#shipping").val ()  ==  "LA") 
        {                              
            $('#mydiv').show();
        }
        else
            $("#mydiv").hide();
    }); 
});
```

(OR)
Try to remove 'hidden' class when u want to show the #mydiv

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#shipping').change(function() {
        if ( $("#shipping").val ()  ==  "LA") 
        {                              
            $('#mydiv').removeClass('hidden');
        }
        else
            $("#mydiv").addClass('hidden');
    }); 
});
```

It will work.!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to have the div show when the page reloads with that information you will need to check for the selected information when the page is loading.
Don't make the default display none.  Hide it when you load the page.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#mydiv").hide();

var shipLocation = $("select#shipping").val();
if ( shipLocation ==  "LA") 
    {                              
        $('#mydiv').show();
    }
```

then add your shipping change method.